# Remap search key to power button on Android 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S, and Button Remapper that I see suggested is not working on 2.3 gingerbread for remapping the search/assist button as a power button (because Nexus S power button is known to be fragile).

Is there an alternative to remap the key? Device is rooted, in case that helps.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would suggest a custom launcher, such as ADW. The advantage is that you can change the Search button without changing ROMs, the disadvantage: It only works on the launcher, and not throughout the ROM.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do that if nothing else works out. Still looking for some other solution tho.

Comment: How exactly do I remap search button on ADW? I installed it, and it has improved a lot since I used it months ago!